# ssh2_scp_recv(remote_file,localfile): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, ssh

```
$connection=ssh2_connect('Ip address', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username','password')
$sourceFilePath = 'some remote file path';
$destinationFilePath = '/var/cliscripts/sample.txt';
$fileTransferStatus = ssh2_scp_recv($connection, $sourceFilePath, $destinationFilePath);
```

Above following code is for copying remote file to local directory, but local directory     file not able to open error is appearing:

```
Permission denied, Unable to write to local file
```

Comment: Remote file is not able to copy to local directory,Permission denied error.Please help me regarding this.

Comment: does the apache user has read\write permission on destination folder?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35519227 Jan 23 00:09 admin_oai_noreg_tomagent.log

Comment: you must add the read\write permission for the apache2 user (or www user, it depends on your apache configuration) to the /var/cliscripts/ folder
chown -R apache2 /var/cliscripts/
chgrp -R apache2 /var/cliscripts/

Answer (score 0):

I have given apache permission to folder

chown -R apache2 /var/cliscripts/